# How to configure sequence separator of friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-url, friendly-id

I am using the friendly_id gem version 4.0.9 in Rails 3, and I want to change the default sequence separator from `-` to `_`.

I tried  this but it doesn't work:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id do |config|
     config.base = :name
     config.use :slugged
     config.sequence_separator = "_"
   end
  .....
end
```

Comment: did you find any solution for for configure sequence separator?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [gem's tests on GitHub](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/test/slugged_test.rb#L140):

```
friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged, :sequence_separator => "_"
```

Should work...

Comment: I came here from Google, I'm having the same problem. `sequence_separator` doesn't seem to work, using either the method in the question or the answer. What gives?

Comment: @GeorgeMillo from the friendlyid docs, http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Slugged/Configuration

suquence_seperator : 'The string used to separate a slug base from a numeric sequence.'

Comment: Yeah, I realised that I was misunderstanding what `sequence_separator` is supposed to do - e.g. if your slug is "my-awesome-slug_1234hashforuniqueness5678`, it only affects the `_` between `my-awesome-slug` and the hash, not the `-`s within `my-awesome-slug`. (I hope that made sense.)

Answer (score 2):

**For Friendly_Id Gem 5.x with Rails 4.x** 
(Might also work with lower versions of Friendly_Id Gem or Rails)

---

Add the following method to the model file where you are using Friendly_Id to generate slugs-

```
def normalize_friendly_id(string)
  super.gsub("-", "_")
end
```